# How do I remove the :hover state from a link using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website with the following simplified menu code:

```
<li><a id='link1' class="menu active" href="javascript:doslide(1);">Item 1</a></li>
<li><a id='link2' class="menu" href="javascript:doslide(2);">Item 2</a></li>
<li><a id='link3' class="menu" href="javascript:doslide(3);">Item 3</a></li>
<li><a id='link4' class="menu" href="javascript:doslide(4);">Item 4</a></li>
<li><a id='link5' class="menu" href="javascript:doslide(5);">Item 5</a></li>
```

In my CSS, `.menu:hover` gives the menu links a different background colour, and `.menu.active` indicates the selected screen. `doslide()` is a javascript function for sliding screens in from the left or right based on location, and it works something like this:

```
var currentpanel = 1;
var numpanels = 5;
doslide = function(panelid) {
    if (panelid != currentpanel) {
        $('.menu').blur();
        $('.active').removeClass("active");
        $('#link'+panelid).addClass('active');
        . . .
}
```

I have also added a touchscreen swipe detector, so that in addition to using the menu to move between panels, you can swipe left and right to bring in the next screen. The point is to emulate the functionality of a mobile app.

My problem is that when I use this on my phone, if I tap a menu item to load that screen, and then swipe, the menu item I tapped on still has its `:hover` state. That means you can be on screen 3, but have the menu item for screen 2 highlighted as if you're holding a mouse over it. I thought that `$('.menu').blur();` would fix this, but it doesn't. Is there a straightforward way to remove the `:hover` state from the link? I don't want to remove the mouseover effect entirely, just make the phone no longer think the menu item is being hovered over.

I've also tried having the menu links go to `javascript:;` and attaching events to them for `click`, to no avail. For the swipe, I have tried both methods below:

```
$('#panelholder').swipe({
    swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {
        if (direction == 'left' && currentpanel < numpanels) {
            $('#link_'+(currentpanel+1)).click();
            // doslide(currentpanel+1);
        } else if (direction == 'right' && currentpanel > 1) {
            $('#link_'+(currentpanel-1)).click();
            // doslide(currentpanel-1);
        }
    }
});
```

I've also tried adding `setTimeout(function() {$('body').click().trigger('tap');}, 50);` to no avail.

Comment: This isn't directly related to your question, but your code looks like it came straight out of 1998. `<li><a id='link2' class="menu" href="javascript:doslide(2);">Item 2</a></li>` should be `<li id='link2' class="menu">Item 2</li>`. In other words, don't use a hyperlink as a JavaScript trigger as that is semantically incorrect and requires a bunch of additional code you don't need. Just set up `click` event handlers for each `li` and then in the callback call `doSlide` and pass it that index of the clicked `li` (within its group) plus one.

Comment: Actually, since your way requires manually attaching event listeners when a simple `<a href='javascript...'>` will do, it's _your_ way that requires a bunch of additional code I don't need. But thank you for your uninvited criticism that doesn't address my question, and I hope you have a great day.

Comment: I'm sorry if you took offense at my comment, none was intended. Comments are, after all, just that, comments - - they don't always address the question being asked directly. My suggestion actually reduces the code significantly and follows modern standards and best practices. It also provides better accessibility for those users who rely on assistive technologies. Take my advice or don't, that's up to you. I was just trying to give you some insight into how modern code is written.

Comment: Not offended, but put off by the condescending tone. "Your code looks like it came straight out of 1998" is not the best way to begin a constructive conversation. I do appreciate your insight and intention. However, when your method requires me to write a function that my method does not require, it is in opposition with reality to say that your method _reduces_ the amount of code I have to write. As to the rest, this is for a website backend that will be used by precisely one person, so as long as he's happy, I'm happy :)

Comment: There's no condescension here. Your code uses pre-standards techniques that date back to 1998 - that's not an insult, it's a fact. Also, I don't think you understand the approach I'm advocating. You would remove (entirely) all the `a` elements (along with the mostly redundant manual event handlers) and replace that with a simple loop that sets up all the event handlers dynamically. The result would be code that is much less brittle, much more scalable and code that follows modern standards. But again, take my advice or not. I'm just trying to help you understand what modern code looks like.

Comment: And code that is longer than what I've provided. I'm not saying that you're wrong to say it's against standards - in fact I agree with you. And it should be clear from context that the code above is not final. But it is factually wrong to say that a method that requires writing more code "reduces the code significantly" over a method that does not require writing that code in a project this small.

As to being condescending, when you begin your comment with criticism, you are immediately condescending whether you intend to be or not. Just skip that part and go straight to being helpful ;)

Comment: Again, I'm sorry if you took offense, none was intended. And, again, my solution **reduces** the overall amount of code and the redundancy of the code - it doesn't cause more code than what you already have. I'm not sure why you think you know how much code there is to a solution that I haven't shown you. As for condescending, I've already explained that it is factually correct to say your code looks like it's from 1998 because you are using techniques from that era that shouldn't be used anymore. This is hardly my personal opinion.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's correct. Saying it changes the tone of your comment. You also talk about "what modern code looks like" which implies that I have never seen it before. And in your most recent comment you question how I'd know how much code there is in a solution _you_ haven't shown me, which implies that I couldn't figure it out for myself. In fact if you read the bottom of my question, you'll see that I tried that method too, so obviously I know how big it is. And regardless of how big or little the code is, it's more javascript than I had before, ergo not less. Now please stop.

Comment: Yeah, OK. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to wrap your :hover css in a media query so it doesn't apply to mobile devices.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) { 
  myElement:hover {}
}
```

Comment: You know, I was so fixated on removing the state that it never occurred to me to prevent it from showing up in the first place. This solution should have been obvious. Thanks!

Comment: Here is a more robust media query for excluding mobile devices: `@media (hover: hover) and (pointer: fine) { ... }` ([source](https://medium.com/@ferie/detect-a-touch-device-with-only-css-9f8e30fa1134)).